# I want to read a table from text file and assign each column to an array

Tags: c#

i want to store each row in a different array. below is the code i tried.
but it doesn't not work, it only splits the last line and store values in "valueperline" array

first 11 rows are source text. file and screen shot of console

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
namespace BBS_optimize
{ 

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int i = 0; int j = 0; int k =0; string[] valueperline = new string[0]; string[] lines = new string [0];
           lines = File.ReadAllLines("Table1.txt");
            for (i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
            }
            for (j = 0; j<lines.Length; j++)
            { valueperline = lines[j].Split('\t');

            }
            for (k = 0; k < 44; k++)
            { Console.WriteLine(valueperline[k]); 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does split all lines, it is just that you are overwriting the same variable (`valueperline`) every iteration so it will only have the value of the last line when the code completes. Make sense?

Comment: This would be an excellent time for you to learn to use the debugger to step through the code, where you can see exactly what it does, what is (and is not) being executed, and trace through the actual logic and flow of the program as it runs.

Comment: @Crowcoder that's the problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use array:

```
string[,] ParseFromFile (string fileName)
{
    // Assume that your table have 10 cols and 100 rows
    string[,] result = new string[10,100];
    string str = File.ReadAllText (fileName);
    // Split each line to arrays
    string[] yourStringArray = str.Split(new[]{'\r', '\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i == 0; i < yourStringArray; i++)
    {
        string[] row = yourStringArray[i].Split(new[]{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        result[i] = row;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Use List:

```
List<List<string>> ParseFromFile (string fileName)
{
    // Your list
    List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();
    string str = File.ReadAllText (fileName);
    // Split each line to arrays
    string[] yourStringArray = str.Split(new[]{'\r', '\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i == 0; i < yourStringArray; i++)
    {
        List<string> row = yourStringArray[i].Split(new[]{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        result.Add(row);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below is a solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<string>> lst = new List<List<string>>();
        string[] lines = new string[0];
        lines = File.ReadAllLines("tableX.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < lines.Length; j++)
        {
            var line = lines[j].Split(' ').ToList();
            lst.Add(line);
        }
        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < item.Count; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```